# Setting the innerHTML not working in Internet Explorer 9.0

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript function that splits up a row of textboxes into multiple rows.
The function is as below :

```
function newline(componentID)
{

    var cols = document.getElementById(componentId).getElementsByTagName('td');
    var colslen = cols.length;
    var i = -1;
    var tempInnerHTML = '<tbody><tr>';

    while (++i < colslen)
    {
        tempInnerHTML += '<td>' + cols[i].innerHTML + '</td>'
        if ( i == 9 || i == 19 || i==29 ) { tempInnerHTML += '</tr><tr>'; }
    }
    tempInnerHTML += '</tr></tbody>';
    document.getElementById(componentId).InnerHTML = tempInnerHTML; 

}
```

The function works fine on FireFox but does not work in IE 9.0
The reason being `document.getElementById(componentId).InnerHTML = tempInnerHTML;`
i.e. we cannot directly set the innerHTML in IE 9.0

so I tried changing the above function to :

```
function newline(componentID)
{

    var cols = document.getElementById(componentId).getElementsByTagName('td');
    var colslen = cols.length;
    var i = -1;
    var tempInnerHTML = '<tbody><tr>';

    while (++i < colslen)
    {
        tempInnerHTML += '<td>' + cols[i].innerHTML + '</td>'
        if ( i == 9 || i == 19 || i==29 ) { tempInnerHTML += '</tr><tr>'; }
    }
    tempInnerHTML += '</tr></tbody>';
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = tempinnerHTML;
    document.getElementById(componentId).appendChild(div.firstChild.tBodies[0]); 

}
```

However, the above function does not work on FireFox as well as IE 9.0
The problem being the statement

```
document.getElementById(componentId).appendChild(div.firstChild.tBodies[0]);
```

I need to get the function to work on both FireFox as well as IE 9.0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `componentID` the id of a `table` element ?

Comment: yes! componentID is the id of a table element.

Answer (score 3):

This can't work on no browser.

Change

```
document.getElementById(componentId).InnerHTML = tempInnerHTML;
```

to

```
document.getElementById(componentId).innerHTML = tempInnerHTML;
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.

---

Following your edit : You have another error :

```
tempInnerHTML += '</tr></tbody>';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = tempinnerHTML;
```

You **can't** add a tbody to a div. Some browsers might try to fix it for you by inserting a table but that's not a specified behavior. You should create a `table` element (and skip the firstChild step). And you probably should not even use this div or table anyway, it's a useless step : directly create the tbody and append it.

Comment: Hi! this was a typo.. I checked my code.. I have the statement in proper casing yet it does not work. Also the error is in the below statement : document.getElementById(componentId).appendChild(div.firstChild.tBodies[0]);